# Image Morphing with Custom Vertices

Tags: graphics, image-manipulation, transform

I am looking for a simple tool with which I can assign vertices to specific points in my original image, and then assign new locations for some/all of these vertices and have it transform the image accordingly by stretching/squashing the image sections between and around the vertices.

Does anyone know of a (preferably free) tool that can do this simply on large res images (6000x4000 pixels... I have plenty of memory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem by using ImageMagick and a manually crafted file of coordinate transformations. The result wasn't perfect, but it did give me the required amount of precise control.